# Using external data in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, singleton, laravel-5.5

I'm building a site that has to display data collected from an external web service. This service provides multiple data endpoints that are all authenticated against via OAuth.

Rather than each view having to hit an internal method to generate this data (and login to the external service each time) it seems like it'd be much better to create a singleton that will (lazy) connect to the data provider service when a view needing the data is first loaded, and then the various methods supporting the views could just call this same service provider to get the data.

Would this be best in the Laravel world as a service provider? As a helper class with a singleton? Or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Your Laravel application boots from scratch every time it receives a request (you can cache objects from a previous request, but not an instantiated service), so it won't be possible to create a service that keeps running authenticated between requests (at least with PHP).

It's not uncommon to create a service and authenticate once per request.

That being said, you can create a service and bind it to the container using $app->bind() or $app->singleton().

Docs about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container